# Why do i get undefined when passing parameter to mapped getter?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have some getters set up, you pass them an id and they return the relevent data. So i've mapped these into a component, however when passing a param the param is undefined.

Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        props: ['id'],

        computed: mapGetters({
            subCategories: ['categories/getSubcategories'](this.id),
            category: ['categories/getCategory'](this.id)
        })
    }
</script>
```

Getter:

```
getCategory: (state, id) => {
    return state.categories.filter(category => category.id === id);
},
```

The error being:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

If I pass it a hard coded parameter, e.g `category: ['categories/getCategory'](106)` then I get:

> ['categories/getCategory'] is not a function

Where am I going wrong here?

EDIT: Here's my store: [image: console.log(this.$store)]

Comment: could you provide the `state` object?

Comment: try `['categories/getCategory'][this.id]` use brackets

Comment: So the getters aren't in the `state` object, they're in the `getters` object. And brackets don't work - i found a another post where they started with `[ ]` and replaced them with `( )`

Comment: please share your store

Comment: Added a screenshot of it, cant seem to copy and paste it out.

Comment: the given screenshot doesn't add any value, another thing to notice : `categories/getCategory` is right to do do that using /?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? The store is namespaced: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/688), it seems what you need is to return a function in your getters and then call the method in the computed property, i.e. your getter:

```
getCategory: state => {
  return id => state.categories.filter(category => category.id === id);
}
```

And then in `computed` property:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'categories/getSubcategories', 
    'categories/getCategory'
  ]),
  subCategories () {
    return this['categories/getSubcategories'](this.id)
  },
  category () {
    return this['categories/getCategory'](this.id)
  }
}
```