# Mapped getters are undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I've mapped a set of getters into my component and am trying to call them with a parameter in methods, however the getters are coming up as undefined. I've mapped them following an answer on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857966/why-do-i-get-undefined-when-passing-parameter-to-mapped-getter)

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
        'products/getCategoryProducts', 
        'categories/getSubcategories', 
        'categories/getCategory'
    ]),

    products () {
        return this['products/getCategoryProducts'](this.id)
    },

    subCategories () {
        return this['categories/getSubcategories'](this.id)
    },

    category () {
        return this['categories/getCategory'](this.id)
    },
}
```

The error being:

> TypeError: this.categories/getCategory is not a function

I've console logged `this`:

[image: console.log(this)]

[image: console.log(this) continued]

Edit: Updated code following @Luceos answer:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        getProducts: 'products/getCategoryProducts', 
        getSubCategories: 'categories/getSubcategories', 
        getCategory: 'categories/getCategory'
    }),

    products () {
        return this.getProducts(this.id)
    },

    subCategories () {
        return this.getSubCategories(this.id)
    },

    category () {
        return this.getCategory(this.id)
    },
}
```

Which returns:

> TypeError: this.getCategory is not a function

My getter:

```
getCategory: (state, id) => {
    return state.categories.filter(category => category.id === id);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code of getters in store?

Comment: Added my getter to the question

Comment: So if your getter is `getCategory` you should use `    ...mapGetters({
        getCategory: 'getCategory'
    }),`

Comment: Sorry it's been namespaced into `categories/getCategory` because i've split stores over multiple files.

Comment: I just saw @Luceos answer. His answer should work

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Just realised the output in my question was wrong, it returns `TypeError: this.getCategory is not a function`

Comment: Try making getter like this:
getCategory: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.categories.filter(category => category.id === id);
}

Comment: @roliroli - looks correct, getter should be a higher order function to accept a param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        products: 'products/getCategoryProducts', 
        subcategories: 'categories/getSubcategories', 
        category: 'categories/getCategory'
    }),

    products () {
        return this.products(this.id)
    },

    subCategories () {
        return this.subcategories(this.id)
    },

    category () {
        return this.category(this.id)
    },
}
```

And your getters should be functions expecting the id for example:

```
getCategory: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.categories.filter(category => category.id === id);
}
```

Make sure to take a look at docs [Method-Style Access](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access)

Comment: That doesn't account for the parameters being passed to the getters though. Having the methods names the same as the mapped getters might cause conflicts too right?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try it and let me know if worked for you

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper), you can refactor this to use object style accessors:

```
...mapGetters({
  // map `this.doneCount` to `this.$store.getters.doneTodosCount`
  doneCount: 'doneTodosCount'
})
```

So in your situation:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('products', {
        products: 'getCategoryProducts'
    }),
    ...mapGetters('categories', {
        subCategories: 'getSubcategories', 
        category: 'getCategory'
    }),
}
```

Then use that (assuming those getters have arguments):

```
this.products(this.id)
```

I've taken a look at the [shopping cart example](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/shopping-cart/components/ShoppingCart.vue), this is their snippet, updated the above to match:

```
...mapGetters('cart', {
      products: 'cartProducts',
      total: 'cartTotalPrice'
    })
```

Comment: I've updated my question, however the mapped getter is now undefined

Comment: you could potentially go back to array notation on the mapGetters categories one if you'd like

Comment: Yeah i'm still getting `this,getCategory is not a function`, so it not seeing the mapped method

Comment: There's no `this.getCategory`, we mapped it to `category` instead.. See the snippet above.

Comment: No i mapped it to `getCategory` to prevent conflict with the other method names. However i've solved it, my getter wasn't setup right

Comment: Thanks for your help, you both contributed to the resulting answer.

Answer (score 0):

i had this error:

`TypeError: (0 , vuex__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default) is not a function`

and I noticed my import was default import.
so it was like this :

`import mapGetters from "vuex";`

turned to named import and problem solved :

`import {mapGetters} from "vuex";`